# Create a Percentage with 2 Tables

Tags: sql, mysql

I am new in creating table and sql.

I have two tables Region 1 and Region 2 as seen below. Now I want to create a third table in order to compute and get the percentage I already have the formula just need to have the finale table as below.

Formula: (Total / Grand Total) * 100

Region 1

| Territories | Total |
| --- | --- |
| NAM | 30,000 |
| EMEA | 1,375,390 |

Region 2

| Grand Total |
| --- |
| 5170701 |

FINAL TABLE

| Territories | Total | % |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NAM | 30,000 | 0.58% |
| EMEA | 1,375,390 | 26.59 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below query should work. It takes columns from those two tables and give the required output.

```
SELECT A.TERRITORIES, A.TOTAL, ((A.TOTAL * 100.0) / B.GRAND_TOTAL) AS PERCENTAGE FROM REGION1 A, REGION2 B;
```